# How to retrieve data by searching on hashed password in CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 3.3

```
Table: block_logins
******************** 1. row *********************
           id: 1
   ip_address: 
     username: 
     password: $2y$10$5ijG2YNs74pirWUAkDu2UuObWMmAjW25dvoR8rXIMCcym9t5AP6VG
  description: test
      expires: 2017-06-17 13:48:02
date_modified: 2017-06-16 13:49:09
 date_created: 2017-06-16 13:48:02
*************************************************
```

Code:

```
$passwordHasherObj = new \Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher();
        $password = $passwordHasherObj->hash($password);

return $this->find('all')
            ->where(["OR" => ["ip_address" => $users_ip, "username" => $username, "password" => $password]])
            ->andWhere(["expires >" => date("Y-m-d H:m:s")])
            ->execute()->fetchAll('assoc');
```

I am trying to get data from this block_logins table by matching on ip_address or username or password.

The passwords are hashed before they are saved in this table, So when I try to execute this query it's not matching on password, and returning zero rows.

Is there a way to use DefaultPasswordHasher's check() in find(), or any other way to implement this?

Comment: That hash looks like it came from a `password_hash()` **so no**, even if you have the plain text password you cannot get the same hash from it even if you try and re-use `password_hash()` that is the beauty/security of using `password_hash()`

Comment: The only way to do this is to fetch on ip and or username, and then use the `password_verify()` or whatever Cake wraps around that function to test if the plain test password matches the hashed version. That will ensure the hash algo uses the same salt and the same number of rounds to regen the hash for testing

Comment: @RiggsFolly I suppose that's the only way.